# How to change the reference style

Tags: citing, ieeetran

I am using the IEEE transactions journal Latex file. I'd like to change the style of "cite" and "reference" from

[image]

and

[image]

to

[image]

and

[image]

I've been looking at some internet findings on how to change these forms... but I couldn't.

==================================================================
Code in file of `.tex`

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
///////////////////////////////////
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}
```

---

Code in file of `.bib`

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
    CTLuse_article_number = "yes",
    CTLuse_paper = "yes",
    CTLuse_forced_etal = "no",
    CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "50",
    CTLnames_show_etal = "50",
    CTLuse_alt_spacing = "yes",
    CTLalt_stretch_factor = "4",
    CTLdash_repeated_names = "yes",
    CTLname_format_string = "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}",
    CTLname_latex_cmd = "",
    CTLname_url_prefix = "[Online]. Available:"
 }
```

---

Code in another file of `.bib`

```
\bibliographystyle{mybstfile}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
```

---

I have five files on my Overleaf.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please confirm that you're using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style. Please also tell us which citation management package (if any) -- examples would be `cite` and `natbib` -- you employ.

Comment: There is more than one "IEEE transactions journal Latex file". Please be more specific about your document setup.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!